# Loggin in with facebook url issue

Tags: jquery, facebook, oauth-2.0

I've looked around and search but can't seem to find the answer to this.  I have a login with facebook button on my site, and I've setup the app on developer.facebook.com according to what I've read.  But not sure why I keep coming up with this,
error:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

Settings in facebook app:

```
Basic Settings:
   App domains: www.olympusmons.com

Select how your app integrates with Facebook
   Website with Facebook Login
       Site URL:  http://www.olympusmons.com
```

Now the url I am trying to log in from is http://www.olympusmons.com/xxx/ 
I followed this [tutorial](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/) I changed the appid, not sure what else am I doing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Ok in case some else needs this:

when specifying the App Domains, you must use all possibles:

```
Basic Settings:
   App domains: www.xxxx.com, xxxx.com
```